# Postfix to SMTP Relaying

Tags: postfix

I have a few VPS' with Postfix installed on them however I have an issue where the email do not get through to Outlook.com.

My temporary solution / workaround was to just buy a shared hosting package and forward/relay the emails through the shared hosting package.

Now I have several domains (let's say that they are: `foo.com`, `.bar.com`, `baz.com`) whose email is currently handled by the servers. I know that it is possible to set up Postfix to relay mail to another server but if I enable that, will the sent emails still land in the "Sent" IMAP folder on the local server or will they go to the remote IMAP folder? If the answer is remote then is it possible to keep a copy on the local server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use SMTP relay to use another SMTP server, for the sender/client it remains transparent. The relay happens between one SMTP server to another (after the emails have been sent by the client). IMAP is used by the client/user to connect to the server to read or sync emails.
As long as you are using the same IMAP server, sent emails will remain on the same IMAP server that you are using to connect to. In your case, to your question

> will the sent emails still land in the "Sent" IMAP folder on the local server?

**Yes, it will**.

Here is a post on this topic you can have a look for better understanding: [What are SMTP relays and smarthosts?](https://serverfault.com/questions/325997/what-are-smtp-relays-and-smarthosts)

Comment: @sebix you are absolutely right. I have edited my answer.