Difference between Smart Host SMTP and Email Marketing Platform
I have a Newsletter operation am currently trying to handle for an inhouse agency.
They were having issues with deliverability of their Newsletter campaigns while using a general Email Marketing Platform, the Platform advised a Private sending IP for better chances - but that's outside the agency budget for now, besides that, some tests I carried out showed the domain seemed quite fine, but issues likely were from the Email Marketing Platform and so the need to move to a better service..
While I was researching possible platforms with a low budget but good deliverability rate, I stumbled upon a Smart Host SMTP (MAIL.BABY to be specific and subsequently TurboSMTP) and from the contents and information I have gone through online, they seemed like an intermediary between your mail and recipient, that is, you just send a mail to them and then they do the forwarding to improve deliverability.
What is the difference between these platforms (because definitely there seemed to be a difference) called Smart Host SMTP and General Email Marketing Platform like Mailchimp, Elastic Mail, Brevo, Mailgun, Affisend and the rest of them, that allows you to actually create the Newsletter campaign on their server and send directly from them.
At what point would I need to use them? (Is it applicable in the current issue am Troubleshooting)
Am I misunderstanding their mode of operation and they are doing just same thing in different order/ways?
I hope I was detailed enough, I am open to any further inquiry that might help clarify.
I have advised they tried segmenting the contacts from the current Email Marketing Platform from the delivered contacts to see and it was the same.
I have also done some lookup with MXToolbox to see where the issue lied or if blacklisted, all came with green ticks for the domain, also I had sent a sample mail of similar Campaign to an Email-tester generated mail-address to test spam ratio on deliverability and I got over 80% score of content quality.
Need some help, or perhaps there's something I am missing

"What is the difference between this platforms(Because definitely there seemed to be a difference) called Smart Host SMTP and General Email Marketing Platform like Mailchimp, Elastic Mail, Brevo, Mailgun, Affisend and the rest of them..." There isn't really one. You can set up most of those others to send via SMTP instead of API if you want. https://serverfault.com/questions/325997/what-are-smtp-relays-and-smarthosts

There is some difference, though difficult to measure from outside: If the provider exclusively peddles "campaigns", they are more likely covered by wholesale blocks. If the provider deliberately mixes mass mailings and 1-on-1 communication, their usefulness will be more uniform across destinations - not necessarily an advantage. Now about providers that make you pay "outside the agency budget" dollars for something that is almost free (a network address is little more than a number), that is less of an email question and more a matter of what business practices you are willing to tolerate.

I think "email marketing platform" is kind of a "smarthost" that is specifically dedicated to relay marketing mass mail. In other words, one is the subtype of another.
